# Perl or Sed to remove a web virus

Tags: macos, virus, sed, perl

I recently ran across a bit of code injected to all of the files on a web site and I need to use perl or sed to remove it across all the files.

I am having trouble coming up with the exact pattern due to escaping.

I need to match and replace (with nothing) the following text

/*0242d5*/
.. javascript here ...
/*0242d5*/

Comment: restore from your backups. its both quicker, and cleaner.

Comment: Backup? I don't have any :’(

Comment: You should change your website security rules. If it has been possible to inject some JavaScript into these files they will try to do it again. Do you really want to infinitely run these Sed or Perl scripts? It should be usefull

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to suffice when I tested it.

`sed -i 's/\/0242d5\/ .. javascript here ... \/0242d5\///' *.extension`